# Mapstruct with two different sources

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm trying to do the mapping between source and target.

```
@Data
@Builder
@Getter
public class Source {
    public String str3;
}

@Data
@Builder
@Getter
public class Target {
  public String str1;
  public String str2;
  public AnotherObj anotherObj;
}

@Data
@Builder
@Getter
public class AnotherObj {
  public String str3;
  public String str4;
}
```

I have a mapper like this

```
@Mapping(target = "anotherObj", source = "request", qualifiedByName = "mapAnotherObjToSource")
@Mapping(target = "anotherObj.str4", source = "str4")
Target convert(Source request, String str4);
```

But when I do this, I get an error like this:
`Java: No read accessor found for property anotherObj in target type.`

I have my getter, what could be missing?

I tried using `@AfterMapping` like this

```
@AfterMapping
default void handleStr4(@MappingTarget Target target, Source source, String str4) {
if (target.getAnotherObj() != null) {
    target.getCardMetadataInfo().setStr4(str4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem with Lombok, but with the builder pattern in combinations like this.

You have several options:

- Do not use nesting in the target and provide an intermediate method
- Tell MapStruct not to use the lombok builder in this mapper with `@Mapper(builder = @org.mapstruct.Builder(disableBuilder = true))`

For more information on why this problem occurs, and an example with an intermediate method, see this comment in the [MapStruct GitHub issue](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/3353#issuecomment-1698267950).

Answer (score 0):

```
// Set str4 value into handleStr4 method
@AfterMapping
default void handleStr4(Source source, @MappingTarget Target target, 
   String str4) {
       if (target.getAnotherObj() != null) {
           target.getAnotherObj().setStr4(str4);
   }
}
```

Comment: Needed the 
````
@AfterMapping
default void handleStr4(@MappingTarget Target target, Source source, String str4) {
if (target.getAnotherObj() != null) {
    target.getCardMetadataInfo().setStr4(str4);
    }
}
````

This now gets rid of the error, but is not setting the value as expected

Comment: Try with set value into handleStr4() method